# Why doesn't Activator.CreateInstance pass constructor exception when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, constructor

I'm using Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate an object and I'm finding that if the object's constructor throws an exception, Visual Studio seems to regard the exception as "user unhandled" even if I wrap the call to Activator.CreateInstance in a try/catch. See the following example:

```
    class NumberDisliker
    {
        public NumberDisliker(int number)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}? I dislike {0}.", number));
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var blah = new NumberDisliker(5);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught using 'new'.");
            }

            try
            {
                var blah = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NumberDisliker), 5);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught using Activator.CreateInstance");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

When running in debug mode from Visual Studio, execution is stopped when the Exception gets thrown in the constructor. However when I run the executable directly (from outwith Visual Studio), it outputs the two WriteLine messages as expected without halting execution.  My best guess is that Visual Studio is unable to work out that the Exception is handled, but I'm not sure why.

Edit: As an addendum, if I opt to "continue" execution after the exception helper has stopped it, the program finishes with the expected output.

Comment: This is perhaps relevant to your settings in the menu: `Debug > Exceptions`

Comment: I've tried the setting mentioned in Eoin Campbell's answer but it doesn't seem to affect this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the visual studio options page, under debugging.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Debugger.General)&rd=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Debugger.General%29&rd=true)

There's an option there called

**Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries** which can come into effect when calling using reflection. (point #3 under this section in the above link)

Comment: This sounded promising but that option seems to be unchecked by default. Whether I check it or not, I see the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `setting Debug > Exceptions`, where you can set which exceptions to break the execution